# What are the files which are not safe to push to GitHub as Public Repository

Tags: flutter, github

I was planning to push my app to git hub as a public repository but i wanted to know weather android/ ios/ linux/ windows/ linux/ folders are safe to push

I had seen repositories which had those files pushed but I'm still not sure weather to make it public or no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to hide the whole folder. you can add the following to your git ignore to hide all the necessary files

```html
# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Web related

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Android Studio will place build artifacts here
/android/app/debug
/android/app/profile
/android/app/release

# fvm 
.fvm/flutter_sdk
```

Comment: So all the default files are enough to keep the project safe

Comment: what's safe to you? you should keep all the config files and API keys separate and never publish them on git.